# Node.js - Native HTTP how to delete cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

In the native HTTP module for Node.js. I am trying to delete cookies, but the cookies are never deleting! What I am trying to do is that when there is an error, the app deletes all cookies. The cookies are never changing though.

```
if (proxy.error.message.code == 'HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW') {

                    var array = [];

                    req.headers['cookie'].split('; ').forEach(cookie => {


                        array.push(cookie += `; maxAge=0;`);

                    });

                    console.log(array)
                    
                    res.writeHead(200, { 'Set-Cookie': array})

                    return res.end();

                }
```

I really need help specifically in normal Node.js HTTP and not Express.js. I would really love it!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the mdn about cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Its "Max-Age" not "maxAge"

```js
const http = require("http");


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    // set the cookies with a lifetime
    if (false) {

        console.log("set coookies");

        // set test cookies
        res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", [
            `key1=value1; Max-Age=${60 * 60 * 24};`,
            `key2=value2; Max-Age=${60 * 60 * 24};`
        ]);

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();

        return;

    }


    // remove cookies from client
    let cookies = req.headers["cookie"].split(";").map((cookie) => {
        return `${cookie}; Max-Age=0;`;
    });

    res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookies);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();

});



server.listen(1234, "0.0.0.0");
```